# LEFT JOIN delaying query by 5 seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT DISTINCT(journey.id), line.name, journey.departure
FROM journey
INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
INNER JOIN service ON service.id = journey.service
INNER JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
INNER JOIN line ON line.service = service.id
INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
INNER JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = "370023292"
INNER JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pattern.section AND pl2.from_sequence < pl.from_sequence
WHERE journey_day.day = 1 AND CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end AND operator.id = "TMTL"
ORDER BY journey.departure
```

Above is a MySQL query that takes approximately 0.05 seconds to run.

As soon as I append this `LEFT JOIN journey_code ON journey_code.journey = journey.id` it adds another 4-6 seconds to the query. I feel this is something to do with a second reference to the `journey.id` column in the `ON` clause. Why is this `LEFT JOIN` delaying the query results so much?

Information  about `journey_code` table:

```
id(INT 11 PK AI) | journey(VARCHAR 128) | code(VARCHAR 16)
```

Both the `journey` and `code` have indexes. I've tried a composite index on the two and this didn't speed up the query in any way.

The result of an `EXPLAIN` prepended to the query: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKrTn.png

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Please add the output of EXPLAIN <your statement> to your question.

Comment: @VMai Sure, I will add this now. Please bear with me 1 moment.

Comment: @VMai I have updated the question with an `EXPLAIN`

Comment: You are seriously joining 8 tables?

Comment: @TJ What is the alternative? Have you not joined multiple tables before? The fact it takes 0.05 seconds to join 7 tables and 6 seconds to join 8 tables doesn't tell you something might be up with the join on the last table?

Comment: What is the type of `journey.id`? It is not `VARCHAR 128`, is it?

Comment: No, it is INT 11 primary key, auto inc

Comment: Can you try to reproduce it using something like http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: @jskidd3 so why isn't `journey_code.journey` not an `INT 11` as well?

Comment: @Keeper I could do but I've just had to annonyingly run out of the office so I'm on my phone, will do as soon as I'm back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the above query a subquery:

```
SELECT j.*, jc.<whatever>
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT journey.id, line.name, journey.departure
      FROM journey
      INNER JOIN journey_day ON journey_day.journey = journey.id
      INNER JOIN service ON service.id = journey.service
      INNER JOIN operator ON operator.id = service.operator
      INNER JOIN line ON line.service = service.id
      INNER JOIN pattern ON pattern.id = journey.pattern
      INNER JOIN pattern_link pl ON pl.section = pattern.section AND pl.from_stop = "370023292"
      INNER JOIN pattern_link pl2 ON pl2.section = pattern.section AND pl2.from_sequence < pl.from_sequence
      WHERE journey_day.day = 1 AND
            CURDATE() BETWEEN service.date_start and service.date_end AND
            operator.id = 'TMTL'
    ) j left join
    journey_code jc
    ON jc.journey = j.id
ORDER BY j.departure
```

The way MySQL works, it should run the subquery and materialize it.  If you have an index on `journey_code(journey)`, the join should be fast.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I will try this in a moment and let you know if it's an improvement

Comment: Absolutely fantastic! Thank you so much this works a dream! The 12 hour investigation is drawn to a close 8-)